# What is the advised approach to loading a large JS library on demand in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that depends on a heavy JS library. I want to have this library load on demand, e.g. when a certain element is found in the DOM, so that it doesn't consume memory when not needed.

What is the advised approach to achieve that? Should I load the heavy lib in the *content* script, should I inject it via the *background* page, or should I take any other approach?

Thanks.

Comment: [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API with `RequestContentScript` appears to be exactly what you need but the doc claims that `RequestContentScript` isn't supported on Stable channel so do some testing first.

Comment: @wOxxOm It is supported on stable: https://crbug.com/409147. What is "a large" library? How often do you need it? What does your extension do?

Comment: @rob-w the library is about 300k compressed. I am not sure it that is considered big, but I certainly don't think it should load with each tab, unless it's needed. The extension looks for tags in the DOM, parses them and converts them into their expanded value.

Comment: @miniml If the library heavily depends on the DOM, you cannot offload it to the background page. You could lazily load the script by fetching the library code using XHR and then `eval`ing it.

Comment: @RobW: The library does **not** depend on the DOM. It provides Math/Crypto primitives. Would you still advise me using XHR to load it?

Comment: @miniml Maybe, maybe not. Could you make your question less vague? At the very least state how you use the library in terms of triggers, frequency, input/output size, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` from a background page, for example:

```js
// in content.js
if (isLibraryNeeded()) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('insert-lib');
}
```

```js
// in background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, {tab}) => {
    if (message === 'insert-lib') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.index, {
            file: 'big-library.js'
        });
    }
});
```